# async repositories tests problem with execute insert in database test data

Tags: python, pytest

I have a fixture with a session and I call it to add to the test database in another fixture and I get an error (https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8NAU.png)

```
@pytest.fixture
async def session(transaction_context: AsyncTransactionContext):
    async with transaction_context:
        session = transaction_context.current_session
        if session.is_active():
            session.begin_nested()
        else:
            session.begin()

        yield session

        await session.rollback()

@pytest.fixture(scope='function', autouse=True)
async def get_project_matrix_result(session):
    lines_projects = [
        {
            'id': 1,
            'name': 'VODOKANAL PRO',
            'is_active': True,
            'description': 'str',
            'customer': 'viktor',
            'chat_url': 'str',
            'mvp_date': datetime(2023, 1, 6),
        },
        {
            'id': 2,
            'name': '10312',
            'is_active': True,
            'description': 'str',
            'customer': 'ne_viktor',
            'chat_url': 'str',
            'mvp_date': datetime(2023, 1, 7),
        },
    ]

    lines_projects_photos = [
        {
            'id': 1,
            'project_id': 1,
            ' filename': 'str',
            'content_type': 'image',
            'url': 'str',
            'url_expire': datetime(2023, 1, 7),
        },
        {
            'id': 2,
            'project_id': 2,
            ' filename': 'str',
            'content_type': 'image',
            'url': 'str',
            'url_expire': datetime(2023, 1, 7),
        }
    ]
    lines_users = [
        {
            'id': 1,
            'first_name': 'Kirill',
            'middle_name': None,
            'last_name': 'Nibudkin',
            'birth_date': None,
            'email': 'kirill.nibudkin@automate-business.ru',
            'phone_number': '89503470294',
            'telegram': None,
            'mattermost': None,
        }
    ]

    lines_user_photos = [
        {
            'id': 1,
            'user_id': 1,
            ' filename': 'str',
            'content_type': 'image',
            'url': 'str',
            'url_expire': datetime(2023, 1, 7),
            'photo_type': 1
        },
        {
            'id': 2,
            'user_id': 2,
            ' filename': 'str',
            'content_type': 'image',
            'url': 'str',
            'url_expire': datetime(2023, 1, 7),
            'photo_type': 1,
        }
    ]

    lines_roles = [
        {
            'id': 1,
            'name': 'back',
            'is_visible': True,
            'order': 1,
        },
        {
            'id': 2,
            'name': 'front',
            'is_visible': True,
            'order': 2,
        },
    ]

    lines_managers = [
        {
            'user_id': 1,
            'project_id': 1,
        }
    ]
    lines_user_projects = [
        {
            'user_id': 1,
            'project_id': 1,
            'role_id': 1,
        }
    ]

    await session.execute(tables.projects.insert(), lines_projects)
    await session.execute(tables.projects_photos.insert(), lines_projects_photos)
    await session.execute(tables.users.insert(), lines_users)
    await session.execute(tables.users_photos.insert(), lines_user_photos)
    await session.execute(tables.role.insert(), lines_roles)
    await session.execute(tables.project_manager.insert(), lines_managers)
    await session.execute(tables.users_projects.insert(), lines_user_projects)

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_get_project_matrix(
    # session,
    project_repo,

    get_project_matrix_result,
    exp_res_for_project_matrix
):
    result = await project_repo.get_project_matrix(dtos.ProjectFilters(
        status=None, search=None)
    )
    assert result == exp_res_for_project_matrix
```

The main problem is that I cannot normally access the session and add data to the database.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask]